# Routing problem in Rails 3: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches ...)

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created a custom RESTful action called "post". It appears in TransactionsController as a (public) method called post.

```
resources :transactions do
  member :post do
    post :post
  end
end
```

I've got a form configured as follows:

```
<form action="/transactions/25/post">
   ...
   <input id="transaction_submit" commit="commit" type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

When I hit the "Post" button, my server receives:

```
POST "/transactions/25/post"
```

I expect this to call the "post" method in my TransactionController but instead I'm getting a routing error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/transactions/25/post"):
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

James

Comment: I suppose you mean `member do`... not `member :post do`, right? anyway, having the same issue, fun thing is `get :xyz` seems to work.

Comment: You are correct. I should have copied and pasted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally found a solution, the problem is that `form_for` adds the hidden `_method` field with the value `"put"`, because well the transaction already exists, to circumvent this issue I had to do the following:

```
<%= form_for @transaction, :url => post_transaction_path(@transaction), :html => { :method => :post } do |form| %>
```

at least that solved the issue for me, see https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4884-routing-error-for-restful-resource-under-namespace for further reference

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm really using this RESTful method to modify an existing record so I've made it work with a "put" request. Phew! problem solved!

Comment: @James Roscoe: This helped me solve a tangentially-related problem. Rails wasn't finding a custom REST route. Your sample showed me that I need to pass the instance variable to the route *_path method for a PUT request. Thank you so much.